# MariaDB Hourly Report

Tags: report, mariadb, hour

Is there a way to change this MariaDB database query so there is a result for each of the past 6 hours?  This report is to display the total # of e-mails sent during the previous 6 hours.  If there is no record I would like it to return the date/time with "0"  The only way I know how to do this is to put this into a PHP loop.  I was wondering if there is another way.

SELECT `date_messages_sent`, `total_messages_sent` FROM `total_emails_sent_history` WHERE `date_messages_sent` >= DATE_SUB( UTC_TIMESTAMP() , INTERVAL 6 HOUR ) ORDER BY `date_messages_sent` ASC